# PL/SQL: Decide if insert or update a row in a trigger, which is the best way?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I need to write a trigger in Oracle PL/SQL (11g) before inserting each row that checks if a row exists: if it doesn't exists creates a new row, if it does exists updates the existing record.

Which is the best way to do that?

Thanks, Gianluca

Comment: You don't need trigger for this. Oracle has command "merge". https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a `MERGE INTO`:

```
MERGE INTO myTable t
     USING (SELECT 'Smith' AS Name, 1 AS Id FROM DUAL) data -- put your data in here
        ON (t.Id = data.Id)                   -- pk or other matching criteria
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET t.name = data.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT     (Id, Name)
        VALUES (data.Id, data.Name);
```

Buildiing a trigger is possible but no allowed/intended. You should't do this.

You'd try to abbort the insert and do something else. This is not a good idea, because of many thing: hidden logic in db, stupid-clients which are doing wrong things..
You can abort with an error, but it doesn't sound like you idea this way.

If you want to do it you could change to update. Never insert anything and implement a trigger `before update`, which checks if the row exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTableTrigger
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- If row doesn't exist. Insert one before the update..
END;
```

Alternatively you could go the long way and build some views:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/oracle-abort-within-a-before-insert-trigger-without-throwing-an-exception

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm doing a bulk import with SqlDeveloper and I need something that acts on INSERT.

An alternative could be a staging table and a procedure that does the magic, but I can't do that for a long series of not technical issues (not skilled users, no grant on creating other objects, etc.)

Comment: If it's an import you could modify you data and do an ´merge into´: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: MERGE is definitely the best answer.